# Java: getAttribute in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Currently I am working with the following HTML snippet:

```
<div class="cardEntry">
<!-- Balance Block Section (R)-->
<div class="balanceBLock">
<ul>
<li class="balanceText">Actual Balance</li>
<li class="balance">
<strong id="155555520be0019actualBalance">$1.00</strong>
</li>
<li class="balanceText">Available Balance</li>
<li class="balance">
```

I am trying to get the balance: $1.00 using the XPath:

```
.//*[@id='155555520be0019actualBalance']
```

and then attempting to obtain the dollar value using the method .getText however this does not return anything.

I can identify the element just fine using this XPath but it does not return the dollar value with getText method.

Can someone explain how to obtain this value?

Thanks

Comment: What if you make the expression more specific: `//li[. = 'Actual Balance']/following-sibling::li/strong`?

Comment: Please post the code you are using. What are you getting as a result? We don't want to guess what your code was or why you might not be getting the result you expect.

Comment: I think you have to use some `wait` before finding the element ...

Comment: @alecxe this expression has 8 matching nodes I am looking for one that specifically matches one of the 8

Answer (score 1):

Looks like id is dynamic here.. use xpath like below with partial id

```
  //strong[contains(@id,'actualBalance')]
```

or else use

```
//li[. = 'Actual Balance']/following-sibling::li/strong
```

specified by alecxe in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try getAttribute() with any of the below values: "value", "innerText", "innerHTML"